# jQuery to work on WP custom page template

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery script to enable an image mouseover hover effect that I want to use on my WP custom page template but it isn't yet working for me and I assume it is not linking to jQuery. The hover image does not display.

Here is part of the page template code (theme=Twenty_Eleven)

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: rpdcustompagetemplateportfolio
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary">
<div id="content" role="main">
<div id="portfoliop">

<script type='text/javascript'> $(document).ready(function(){ $(".logobutton").hover(function() { $(this).attr("src","<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>images/logobutton_hover50pc.png"); }, function() { $(this).attr("src","<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>images/logobutton50pc.png"); }); }); </script> 

<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logobutton50pc.png" alt="My button" class="logobutton" /> 
<h1>Portfolio</h1>
```

I always get some problem using jQuery & WordPress unfortunately! I assume this is the problem that jQuery not linked/working here.

I am most grateful for help & advice, and look forward to replies, many thanks

(NB for some reason I cannot cut/paste the code in properly here either..apologies)

Comment: did you check console if its showing any script errors ?

Comment: Firebug says no JavaScript on the page...

Comment: replace $ with jQuery ?

Comment: Well-I don't know... I have this bad problem in my head with WP & jQuery...I have added this link to jQuery on the custom page template & it works fine now but I'm not sure at all if this is the best way to do this in WP! <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Please do basic troubleshooting first: ensure you have jQuery enqueued, that you're using the core-bundled version of jQuery, and that your jQuery script accounts for no-conflict mode and has valid syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Probably there are a lot of questions/answers here in wpse that explain this kind of issues and the use of jquery and other js in wordpress.

However,

1. In wordpress **never** put javascripts in template files. Javascript should be in separate .js files.
2. The javascript should be putted in the templates using `wp_register_script` / `wp_enqueue_script` functions using the hook `wp_enqueue_scripts`
3. If one have to pass php variables to js (that being in js files cannot contain `<?php echo $something ?>` the function `wp_localize_script` should be used

This is valid for all javascript files / libraries.

Regarding jQuery

1. **Always** use the jQuery version embedded in Wordpress using `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')`, everytime you deregister jQuery and register a cdn-version of it a cat die. And a dog feels bad.
2. Once we use jQuery embedded in Wordpress, it works in `noConflict` mode, so the `$` alias doesn't works until we use one of the **[noConflict wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)**

### Docs

- [wp_register_script function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)
- [wp_enqueue_script function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)
- [wp_enqueue_scripts hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)
- [wp_localize_script function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

### I'll use your case as example to better explain these arguments.

First you have to create a javascript file, call it "templateportfolio.js" and save it in 'js' folder of your theme, and put your js code there, remember to use noConflict wrappers:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
  $(".logobutton").hover(
    function() { $(this).attr("src", my_script_data.logobutton_hover); },
    function() { $(this).attr("src", my_script_data.logobutton); }
  );
});
```

Here there are here 2 variables: `my_script_data.logobutton_hover` and `my_script_data.logobutton` that you need to pass to the script with `wp_localize_script`.

In fact, in `function.php`, you have to enqueue the script only for the page template and use `wp_localize_script` to pass the url of images:

```
function enqueue_templateportfolio_js() {
  // change the template file name according to your file
  if ( ! is_page_template('templateportfolio.php') ) return;
  wp_enqueue_script('enqueue_templateportfolio_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/templateportfolio.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
  $imagesurl = get_template_directori_uri() . '/images/';
  $images = array(
    'logobutton_hover' => $imagesurl . 'logobutton_hover50pc.png',
    'logobutton' => $imagesurl . 'logobutton50pc.png',
  );
  wp_localize_script('enqueue_templateportfolio_js', 'my_script_data', $images );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_templateportfolio_js');
```

Comment: Don't kill cats! :) Really complete answer, which I had had something like this when I was starting out and trying to run jQuery scripts in WordPress. +1 for sure!

Answer (score 0):

replace $ sign with jQuery example -
  `$(document).ready(function()`

should be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
```

and so on ... replace all $ sign in your script with jQuery, thich is correct way to use jquery in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

The TwentyEleven theme only appears to load jQuery on its `showcase.php` template file. You’ll need to load it yourself in your custom template file, which is easy enough to do. Put the following line of code before the `get_header();` call.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".logobutton").hover(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/images/logobutton_hover50pc.png");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).attr("src","<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>/images/logobutton50pc.png");
});
```

1. You have an unnecessary `});` in your second callback
2. WordPress uses jQuery in [noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), you should use [noConflict Wrappers](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).
3. You need a `/` after the `<?php bloginfo( 'template_directory' ); ?>`
4. Always enqueue your js using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: After [all of us say the same thing](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112085/jquery-to-work-on-wp-custom-page-template/112090#112090) probably OP will not forget it.

Comment: I fixed his code too.

Comment: Yes, I know, but - my opinion - this is not a javascriopt answer / question so fix OP javascript (that, I admin, I not read at all) is not the preminent scope. After that, if you want fix it to better help OP - in my opinion again - is better edit an existing question, instead add 2 lines of js and just write same thing are written in a previous question. You have 2000+ rep so you can freely edit answers...

Comment: The question itself has multiple problems that I enumerated in my answer. The question has both JS and WP issues. Each point I stated directly relates to an error or bad practice so that OP can see WHY his code is not working and what should be done. I appreciate the fact that you wrote a good answer that other people will use and adapt in the future, but here, I guess OP needs to fix his code first and then learn how to optimise it. All those functions/hooks can be overwhelming for a beginner.

Comment: Maybe, however, your js code is wrong, OP one is right.